# Android TextView and how to determine the number of visible characters

Tags: android, textview

How can I determine the number of visible characters that a TextView can display. For example if I change the orientation this number may change. If I change the resolution then also the number of visible characters changes.

Thanks in advance

---

Thank you for your answer.

Currently I am developing a small text based game to become acquainted with the Android API. For that reason I need to know exactly how much characters  can be displayed in the visible area of a TextView widget. I saw an example of Paint but wanted to know if there are better solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you design your GUI such that it does not matter. For example, you can use `android:ellipsize` to deal with strings that are too long for the available space.

There are classes in the 2D drawing APIs (e.g., [`Paint`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html)) that seem to be tied into this, but it does not look like much fun.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ellipsize property but there has been a bug that has been filed on the same

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2254

On the bottom of this page you could find an alternate approach which can draw exactly the number of lines on a given space...